# Where Can I store a hard-coded password on a Windows Phone 8 App?

Tags: c#, security, email, windows-phone-8, passwords

I am making an internal Windows Phone 8 app that needs to connect to an email service to send mail. However, in order to send mail, an email address and password is required. I was provided with an email address and password to be used for sending mail.

My question is, what is the best way for saving the email and password in the app? Since it's hard-coded, is it advisable to put it on the code-behind? Is the code safe from decompiling? Or should I save it on App.xaml? or App.xaml.cs? Should I encrypt the password? But I think that's futile if it's in the app and you can decompile the code to decrypt it.

I know the best way would be to set up our own web service that the app communicates with. Then send the data to be emailed and let that web service handle the authentication for email. However, my supervisor does not want to set up an external web service. He wants a stand-alone WP8.

Do you have any recommendations or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You can't make this secure, so prepare for when it gets compromised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 does not apparently support the `PasswordVault` class that Windows 8 does, but you can store items in Isolated Storage, just like with regular Windows.

Isolated Storage is like a file system except that it is not visible from the outside (except with a specially-written Isolated Storage Explorer). So you can store a file with usernames and passwords there -- preferably encrypted.

For more about Isolated Storage, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

For more about encrypting and decrypting data on Windows Phone, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess I'll just store it in IsolatedStorage encrypted. But can the source code be decompiled on where it decrypts the password to be used in the login?

Comment: Solution with Isolated Storage and code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21007110/2387977

Comment: Since WP8.1 PasswordVault is supported http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx