# Username and Password data Windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am writing a Windows phone 8 app that is using an API to pull in some data that the app will need and to use the api, a username and password is required.  I have been supplied with this username and password and it seems to work, however I am wondering what is the correct way to use this with an app?

Can I simply add something like:

```
string userName = "username";
string passWord = "password";
```

And then just pass those into the `WebRequest` when needed?  Or is there some special way I should store this information in the app?

Just to be clear, the users won't need their own Username or password, this generic one should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can encrypt data in isolated storage. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is a tutorial

In case the link ever goes down here is the code for an app that both writes and reads a secret PIN.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private string FilePath = "pinfile";

private void BtnStore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Convert the PIN to a byte[].
    byte[] PinByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TBPin.Text);

    // Encrypt the PIN by using the Protect() method.
    byte[] ProtectedPinByte = ProtectedData.Protect(PinByte, null);

    // Store the encrypted PIN in isolated storage.
    this.WritePinToFile(ProtectedPinByte);

    TBPin.Text = "";
}

private void WritePinToFile(byte[] pinData)
{
    // Create a file in the application's isolated storage.
    IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    IsolatedStorageFileStream writestream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, file);

    // Write pinData to the file.
    Stream writer = new StreamWriter(writestream).BaseStream;
    writer.Write(pinData, 0, pinData.Length);
    writer.Close();
    writestream.Close();
}

private void BtnRetrieve_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the PIN from isolated storage.
    byte[] ProtectedPinByte = this.ReadPinFromFile();

    // Decrypt the PIN by using the Unprotect method.
    byte[] PinByte = ProtectedData.Unprotect(ProtectedPinByte, null);

    // Convert the PIN from byte to string and display it in the text box.
    TBPin.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PinByte, 0, PinByte.Length);

}

private byte[] ReadPinFromFile()
{
    // Access the file in the application's isolated storage.
    IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    IsolatedStorageFileStream readstream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, file);

    // Read the PIN from the file.
    Stream reader =  new StreamReader(readstream).BaseStream;
    byte[] pinArray = new byte[reader.Length];

    reader.Read(pinArray, 0, pinArray.Length);
    reader.Close();
    readstream.Close();

    return pinArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm not building the API, I was just given access to it by a 3rd party who developed it.

Comment: Then static and readonly are my only recommendations. Otherwise you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks.  Would I need to encrypt the username and password or keep it in IsolateStorage?  It's not accessing any confidential information, but I guess just as a best practice I'm not sure.

Comment: That would be a good idea, I didn't know WP8 had that built in.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any concerns that require you to style your code any different form normal

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://SomeProtectedUrl.com");
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

to keep your username and password in a single spot, so that it would be easy to change you could use

```
public static string uname = "yourUsername";
public static string passwd= "yourPassword";

request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, passwd);
```