# Safly remember login information

Tags: c#, authentication, server, client-server, uwp

I am developing an UWP app and the user is able to register/login. After a successfull login attempt the login information should be saved, so the application can relogin after every start.

Is it safe to save the information or should I modify my service so it works with tokens?

(If a bad guy can get the password, he also can get the token and can take over the user - is it still safer with tokens?)

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007033/username-and-password-data-windows-phone-8-app

Comment: You can post this as an answer so I can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can follow this implementation [Username and Password data Windows phone 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007033/username-and-password-data-windows-phone-8-app)

They use IsolatedStorage and Cryptography

Answer (score 2):

Use Credential locker API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270189.aspx

And deal with tokens instead of passwords for client-side.

Comment: I second that tokens should be used instead of passwords after the initial login. I found the API mentioned by Benjamin very convenient to use. It seems as though it is also encouraged by Microsoft. I am not sure how roaming works though as is mentioned in the article cited by @Benjamin - "This article describes how Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps can use the Credential Locker to securely store and retrieve user credentials, **and roam them between devices** with the user's Microsoft account."

Answer (score 1):

Saving the user's credentials in the app is never a good idea. You should only ave the auth token / cookie / whatever the server issues after login and is required with the requests.

When saving the auth data, encrypt it using `Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection`, sample [here](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/5652991). Os use the `Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault`.